# Manipulate data in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am developing a hybrid mobile app. On the client side I am using html, css ajax/jquery. On the server side(third party) I am using PHP MySql. Now when the user(app) send ajax request to the server, the server will send back details in json format. But before sending the json data, I would like to first manipulate the data in array or add data in array.

This is the sample json data which the server sends.

```
[{
"id":"11",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes A",
"quantity":"1",
"date_open":"2015-01-04",
"paid":"1",
"harvested":"",
"reinvest":null,
"profit":null,
"investment":"3000"
},

{
"id":"12",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes B",
"quantity":"1",
"date_open":"2015-03-01",
"paid":"1",
"harvested":"",
"reinvest":null,
"profit":200,
"investment":"1500"
}]
```

This is my php code.

```
$userid = $_POST['user'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_products WHERE uproducts_user_id = '{$userid}'";
$user_products = db::select($sql);

    $product = array();
    foreach( $user_products as $user_product){
        array_push($product, $user_product);
    }

    $server_msg = $product;

echo json_encode($server_msg);
```

How can I manipulate the array from my database.

1. **FORMATTING and Condition**: I would like to change all `"profit":null`. If profit 'isnull' then echo 'n/a' else echo the amount(with number_format). As well as to `"date_open":"2015-01-04"` to format it in Y-M-dd.
2. **COMPUTATION**: Add another field to an array example for the 1st array with `"id":"11"`. I want to add another field like **total** which is total = investment + profit(if it is not null).

I would like to do this on php server because it is easier for me to format and manipulate the data, than on the client-side. So when I have done this on the server side the json data was already set and ready to display. `I prefer to use php and not in mysql query`.
Thank you.

**Update #1**: I can now manipulate/change the array inside the foreach loop. My problem as of now is on how to add data in array. Example is the total of `user's investment`. I added this code before the loop `total_investment=0`, then inside loop `total_investment += user_product['investment'];`

And should display like this:

```
[{
"id":"11",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes A",
"quantity":"1",
"date_open":"2015-01-04",
"paid":"1",
"harvested":"",
"reinvest":null,
"profit":null,
"investment":"3000"
},

{
"id":"12",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes B",
"quantity":"1",
"date_open":"2015-03-01",
"paid":"1",
"harvested":"",
"reinvest":null,
"profit":200,
"investment":"1500"
},
{
"total_investment":"4500" // how can I add this here?
}]
```

Comment: Where do you want to manipulate these modifications ? 
in PHP or in Mysql query..?
I think you should try this using Mysql.

Comment: I would like to do it only in php not in query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this modification in your `Mysql` query. so, just try this one out..

```
$userid = $_POST['user'];
$sql = "SELECT id,user_id,product,quantity,DATE_FORMAT(date_open, '%y-%M-%d') as date_open:2015-03-01,paid,harvested,reinvest,
COALESCE(profit,'N/A') as profit,investment,COALESCE(profit,0)+COALESCE(investment,0) as total
FROM user_products WHERE uproducts_user_id = '{$userid}'";
$user_products = db::select($sql);

    $product = array();
    foreach( $user_products as $user_product){
        array_push($product, $user_product);
    }

    $server_msg = $product;

echo json_encode($server_msg);
```

If you want this manipulation in `php` code, then please follow the below code..

```
$userid = $_POST["user"];
$user_products = db::select("SELECT * FROM user_products WHERE uproducts_user_id = '{$userid}'");
$product = array();
if(sizeof($user_products)>0){
foreach( $user_products as $user_product){
$profit=$user_product->profit!==null ? $user_product->profit : 0;
$arr=array(
    'id':$user_product->id,
    'user_id':$user_product->user_id,
    'product':$user_product->product,
    'quantity':$user_product->quantity,
    'date_open':$user_product->date_open,
    'paid':$user_product->paid,
    'harvested':$user_product->harvested,
    'reinvest':$user_product->reinvest,
    'profit':$profit!=0 ? $profit : 'N/A',
    'investment':$user_product->investment,
    'total':$user_product->investment+$profit
);
array_push($product, $arr);
}
}
$server_msg = $product;
echo json_encode($server_msg);
```

Comment: I would prefer to do this in php not in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, I would do something like :

```
SELECT 
id,user_id,product,quantity,
DATE_FORMAT(date_open,'%Y-%m-%d'),
paid,harvested,reinvest,
if (profit IS NULL,'n/a',FORMAT(profit,'de_DE')) as profit,
investment,
if (profit IS NOT NULL, investment+profit, NULL ) as total
FROM user_products 
WHERE uproducts_user_id = '{$userid}'
```

Comment: I would like to do it in sql but for some reasons I prefer to use php. Is there a way to do it?